# problem with adding a check constraint to a column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

basically i want to add a check constraint for a column in sql
this what i wrote

```
ALTER TABLE pays ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_foufa CHECK (nom = "amine");
```

it shows this error :

[image]

Comment: That means the table has rows that violate the constraint you're trying to add. You need to fix them before you can add the constraint.

Comment: the syntax is correct ?

Comment: Yes. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html. I'm not sure why the static analysis says that.

Comment: Make sure you are using MySQL 8.0 , as versions prior to that accept the syntax but ignore the actual check.